# not able to edit record by passing text value through form access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a first table called `"BreedingTable"` with primary key `"ID"` and `"TransactionStatus" = "Active"`.

I have "Kidding form" data populated from the combo box to Text fields 
`Text2.value = "ID"` from `BreedingTable`.

When I am done with all the process, I want to change `TransactionStatus` of Breeding table = `Closed`.

I am using the below code but it never works.

Note" if I give exact transaction id number it works fine, 
but if I ask to find based on `text2` it doesn't work.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub exitprograme3()
    Me.Text2.SetFocus
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim Trn As Integer
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("BreedingTable")
    For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
    Me.Text2.SetFocus    
    If rs.Fields("ID") = Me.Text2.Value Then
        rs.Edit
        rs.Fields("BreedingStatus") = "Closed"
        rs.Update
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
    Next i
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Please assist ...

If I type exact transaction id number in below if statement it works

```
If rs.Fields("ID") = "323" Then
```

this works fine.

But if I type like below it doesn't work

```
If rs.Fields("ID") = Me.Text2.Value Then
```

Comment: What does this show you? `Debug.Print "'" & Me.Text2.Value & "'"`

Comment: Change `For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1` to `Do While Not rs.EOF` and change `Next i` to `Loop`

Comment: Thanks for your comment , but it is still not working

Comment: still it works the same way ,,, meaning if i change If rs.Fields("ID") ="323" (which is ID of the transaction i want to change, it works perfectly fine with both logic (do while and next i)...  i also try to get msgbox befor the loop and it disply Me.Text 2 value corrrectly ... Please assist

Answer (score 0):

No loop is needed:

```
Private Sub exitprograme3()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * From BreedingTable")

    rs.FindFirst "[ID] = " & Me!Text2.Value & ""
    ' If ID is text, then quotes:
    ' rs.FindFirst "[ID] = '" & Me!Text2.Value & "'"
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        rs.Edit
            rs.Fields("BreedingStatus").Value = "Closed"
        rs.Update
    End If
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: i am getting error in this line . rs.FindFirst "[ID] = '" & Me!Text2.Value & "'".. error message is like this  "Run Time error 3251"  message is "Operation is not supported for this type of object "